# Round and truncate numeric label in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, arcade

I have a numeric field that I'd like to use as a label in ArcGIS Pro, but would only like to show the first two digits of that field. For example, The value in the table is "7,903,043" but I would like the label on the map to show "7.9".

I've figured out how to use round($feature.sales) to round that field to "7,900,000", but am not sure how to go from that to "7.9".

Comment: Divide by 1 million, no?

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/263113/115

Answer (score 1):

You would need to divide the value by 100,000, then round it, and then divide by 10. The arcade expression would be `Round($feature.sales / 100000) / 10`.